# How to use setTimeout in PureScript v0.7

Tags: purescript

I want to use setTimeout for animation in PureScript like this.

```
loop n =
  if n > 100
  then do
    return Unit
  else do
    print n
    timeout (loop n+1) 30
```

[purescript-timers](https://github.com/CapillarySoftware/purescript-timers) is no longer work in v0.7.

I don't have the slightest idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Use [purescript-js-timers](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-js-timers) from purescript-contrib.
2. Use [purescript-aff](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/2.0.1/docs/Control.Monad.Aff#v:later') (`later'`).

I prefer the later, and here is an example:

```haskell
import Control.Monad.Aff as Aff

update :: forall eff. Action -> State -> EffModel State Action (eff)
update MyAction myState = 
  { state: myState, effects: [ Aff.later' 1000 $ pure MyOtherAction ] }
```

Comment: versioning for purescript-aff link is no longer valid

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to define your own foreign import for `setTimeout`:

```
module SetTimeout where

foreign import data TIMEOUT :: !

foreign import timeout :: forall eff a. 
                               Int -> 
                               Eff (timeout :: TIMEOUT | eff) a -> 
                               Eff (timeout :: TIMEOUT | eff) Unit
```

In your foreign Javascript module, you can define `setTimeout` as follows:

```
"use strict";

// module SetTimeout

exports.timeout = function(millis) {
    return function(action) {
        return function() {
            setTimeout(action, millis);
        };
    };
};
```

You would be able to extend this to work with things like `clearTimeout` if needed.

Some other possible approaches:

- Send a pull request to update `purescript-timers` by following the migration guide on the wiki: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/0.7-Migration-Guide
- Use `later'` from `purescript-aff`: [doc](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/2.0.1/docs/Control.Monad.Aff#v:later')